# Good practice to simulate a Facebook like / dislike system

Tags: javascript

Basically my application will allow you to publish news while it will handle a system of `likes` and `dislikes`

I will use the mongodb database.
Basically I will have a collection that will contain news and an attribute called `likes`, and another called `dislikes`. Both will store an array and this array will be filled with json objects with the users who have registered a `like` or `dislike` respectively.

when a user makes a request to the news list I will return the news and two attributes `like`: `true / false`, `dislike`: `true / false` according to the user making the request.

is this the best way? how does facebook do it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb:

If you don't need the usernames of the users liking the posts, just store the like and dislike counts as integers in an object.

If you need the usernames, store all the users who liked and the users who dislike in separate arrays.

Comment: I need each news item to save the user's id and rating so that when a user is shown any news item that they previously liked, it will be shown as marked.would keep a like attribute and another one called dislike each in an array

Comment: In that case, use the second option. If you need to store more than the username, try storing objects within the array.